# devtools::document error: thinking that part of function description should be imported as a package

Tags: r, devtools

this is the first time that I use `devtools`, so it is probably some silly mistake. Please don't mind that stuff is in Portuguese.
I am writing in this file 3 functions for the package, two of them to be exported `datazoom_pnadc`, `pnadc_painel_basico`:

```
#' @importFrom labelled set_variable_labels var_label
#' @importFrom readxl read_excel
#' @import tidyverse


#' Carregando dados brutos
#'
#' @param diretorio_dados Diretório onde os microdados originais em formato de texto estão armazenados
#'
#' @param diretorio_dicionario Diretório onde o dicionário da pesquisa em formato xls está armaezenado
#'
#' @param ... vetores com datas das pesquisas de interesse no  formato \code{c('trimestre', 'ano')}
#'
#' @return Lista de dataframes, sendo cada entrada um trimestre/ano em \code{...}
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' datazoom_pnadc('./Desktop', './Desktop', c(1, 2000), c(2, 2000))
#'
    datazoom_pnadc <- function(diretorio_dados,
                               diretorio_dicionario,
                               ...) {}

     #' Painel básico
     #'
     #' @param build_data Default \code{TRUE}.
     #' Se \code{TRUE}, implementa primeiro \code{\link{datazoom_pnadc}} e depois
     #' monta paineis de indivíduos. Se \code{FALSE}, a função constrói paneis a partir de dados já carregados no R
     #'
     #' @param dados_prontos Bases de dados para diferentes trimestres da PNAD contínua.
     #' Necessário se \code{build_data = FALSE}
     #'
     #' @param local_dados Diretório onde os microdados originais em formato de texto estão armazenados
     #' caso \code{build_data = TRUE}
     #'
     #' @param local_dicionarios Diretório onde o dicionário da pesquisa em formato xls está armaezenado caso
     #' \code{build_data = TRUE}
     #'
     #' @param periodos Lista de vetores com períodos de interesse no formato
     #' \code{periodos = list(c(trimestre1, ano1), c(trimestre2, ano2), ...)}
     #'
     #' @encoding UTF-8
     #'
     #' @return Lista de dataframes, sendo cada entrada um trimestre/ano
     #'
     #' @examples
     #' PNADC_2012 <- datazoom_pnadc(diretorio_dados = './Desktop',
     #' diretorio_dicionario = './pnadcontinua/Desktop',
     #' c(1,2012), c(2,2012))
     #'
     #' teste <- pnadc_painel_basico(build_data = FALSE,
     #'                              dados_prontos = PNADC_2012)
     #'
     #' teste2 <- pnadc_painel_basico(build_data = TRUE,
     #'                               local_dados = './pnadcontinua',
     #'                               local_dicionario = './pnadcontinua/Dicionario_e_input',
     #'                               periodos = list(c(1,2012), c(2,2012)))
     #' @export
    pnadc_painel_basico <- function(build_data = TRUE, ...){}


    loop <- function(data,
                     interview = 2,
                     int_final = 5){...}
```

After running `devtools::document`, I get the following problems:

```
Updating DatazoomR documentation
Loading DatazoomR
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing pnadc_painel_basico.Rd
Warning messages:
1: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘Carregando’
2: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘brutos’
3: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘dados’
4: datazoom_pnadc.Rd is missing name/title. Skipping
```

I don't know why this happens. For some reason some of the words in the description are thought to be added to the previous line in `import`. And also only the second function is being saved.

Can someone help? It seems to be something related to formatting.

Comment: Try adding `NULL` right after the line `#' @import tidyverse`. Does that fix it?

Comment: @duckmayr Skipping a line and writing ```#' NULL``` ?? I didn't work

Comment: No, writing `NULL`, not `#' NULL`. Sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: Then it also write ```Warning messages:
1: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called ‘NULL’```, although ```datazoom_pnadc.Rd is missing name/title. Skipping``` does not show anymore.

Comment: See my answer demonstrating that this can work, at least given the code you've shown us so far, as well as explaining why you got the original error and why this fix works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a new R package using RStudio's "New Project > New Directory > R package using devtools".

I then added one R file, containing the following:

```
#' @importFrom labelled set_variable_labels var_label
#' @importFrom readxl read_excel
#' @import tidyverse
NULL

#' Carregando dados brutos
#'
#' @param diretorio_dados Diretório onde os microdados originais em formato de texto estão armazenados
#'
#' @param diretorio_dicionario Diretório onde o dicionário da pesquisa em formato xls está armaezenado
#'
#' @param ... vetores com datas das pesquisas de interesse no  formato \code{c('trimestre', 'ano')}
#'
#' @return Lista de dataframes, sendo cada entrada um trimestre/ano em \code{...}
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' datazoom_pnadc('./Desktop', './Desktop', c(1, 2000), c(2, 2000))
#'
datazoom_pnadc <- function(diretorio_dados,
                           diretorio_dicionario,
                           ...) {
    return(NULL)
}

#' Painel básico
#'
#' @param build_data Default \code{TRUE}.
#' Se \code{TRUE}, implementa primeiro \code{\link{datazoom_pnadc}} e depois
#' monta paineis de indivíduos. Se \code{FALSE}, a função constrói paneis a partir de dados já carregados no R
#'
#' @param dados_prontos Bases de dados para diferentes trimestres da PNAD contínua.
#' Necessário se \code{build_data = FALSE}
#'
#' @param local_dados Diretório onde os microdados originais em formato de texto estão armazenados
#' caso \code{build_data = TRUE}
#'
#' @param local_dicionarios Diretório onde o dicionário da pesquisa em formato xls está armaezenado caso
#' \code{build_data = TRUE}
#'
#' @param periodos Lista de vetores com períodos de interesse no formato
#' \code{periodos = list(c(trimestre1, ano1), c(trimestre2, ano2), ...)}
#'
#' @encoding UTF-8
#'
#' @return Lista de dataframes, sendo cada entrada um trimestre/ano
#'
#' @examples
#' PNADC_2012 <- datazoom_pnadc(diretorio_dados = './Desktop',
#' diretorio_dicionario = './pnadcontinua/Desktop',
#' c(1,2012), c(2,2012))
#'
#' teste <- pnadc_painel_basico(build_data = FALSE,
#'                              dados_prontos = PNADC_2012)
#'
#' teste2 <- pnadc_painel_basico(build_data = TRUE,
#'                               local_dados = './pnadcontinua',
#'                               local_dicionario = './pnadcontinua/Dicionario_e_input',
#'                               periodos = list(c(1,2012), c(2,2012)))
#' @export
pnadc_painel_basico <- function(build_data = TRUE, ...){}


loop <- function(data,
                 interview = 2,
                 int_final = 5){
    return(NULL)
}
```

That is, I took exactly your code, added `NULL` immediately after the line `#' @import tidyverse`, and replaced `...` in the body of your functions with a simple `return(NULL)` to have syntactically valid code.

Then I used `devtools::document()` using the RStudio shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, and `document()` ran just fine for me.

If you are still having problems after this step, it is due to code/comments in your package that you have not shown us.

The reason for needing this step is that the Roxygen comments are generally to document objects or to give NAMESPACE directives. Since you do not have any R objects or roclets after

```
#' @import tidyverse
```

it interprets the next Roxygen comments as still belonging to the last roclet, `@import`. So, you need an intervening R object, for which you can use `NULL`.

Comment: It worked now! Thank you! I guess I should have removed some of the comments inside the function definition as well.

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito Glad it worked! Good luck with your package development